# Unknown Column Error (1054) for a Query in a Stored Procedure, that Works in the Query Window

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a strange issue in MySQL.  I wrote a query that aggregates transnational data into hourly chunks.  The query works great in Workbench query window.  I then implemented the query as a stored procedure and I get a 'Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'd.SiteId' in 'field list'' message.

```
SELECT  `d`.`SiteId`, `d`.`TransactionDate`, (`d`.`TimeGrouping` * 10000) as 'HourEndTime', Sum(`d`.`SalesAmount`) as 'TotalSales', count(`d`.`PosTransactionId`) as 'TransactionCount', Sum(`d`.`ItemCount`) as 'ItemCount', `d`.`Currency`
FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT `SiteId`, `TransactionDate`, `TimeGrouping`, `SalesAmount`, `PosTransactionId`, `ItemCount`, `Currency`
        FROM PosSalesDev.Transaction
        WHERE `SiteId` = 31
        AND `TransactionDate` = '2018-06-08') AS `d`
        GROUP BY TransactionDate, TimeGrouping
ORDER BY HourEndTime;
```

The query in the stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`%` PROCEDURE `TransactionGet`(siteId varchar(10),
                                    transactionDate Date)
BEGIN

# Query will remove duplicate records from the aggregated data
SELECT  `d`.`SiteId`, `d`.`TransactionDate`, (`d`.`TimeGrouping` * 10000) as 'HourEndTime', Sum(`d`.`SalesAmount`) as 'TotalSales', count(`d`.`PosTransactionId`) as 'TransactionCount', Sum(`d`.`ItemCount`) as 'ItemCount', `d`.`Currency`
FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT `SiteId`, `TransactionDate`, `TimeGrouping`, `SalesAmount`, `PosTransactionId`, `ItemCount`, `Currency`
        FROM PosSalesDev.Transaction
        WHERE `SiteId` = siteId
        AND `TransactionDate` = transactionDate) AS `d`
GROUP BY TransactionDate, TimeGrouping;

END
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks
Geordie.

Comment: I don't think this will fix your problem.. But try not to use a name for a SP parameter which is also used as column name. It's hard to know what `WHERE \`SiteId\` = siteId` will do. So rename the `siteId` parameter to something like `inSiteId`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid naming parameters as column names. See [13.6.4.2 Local Variable Scope and Resolution](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/local-variable-scope.html).

Try:

```sql
DELIMITER //

CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`%` PROCEDURE `TransactionGet`(
  _siteId varchar(10),
  _transactionDate Date
)
BEGIN

# Query will remove duplicate records from the aggregated data
SELECT
  `d`.`SiteId`,
  `d`.`TransactionDate`,
  (`d`.`TimeGrouping` * 10000) as 'HourEndTime',
  Sum(`d`.`SalesAmount`) as 'TotalSales',
  count(`d`.`PosTransactionId`) as 'TransactionCount',
  Sum(`d`.`ItemCount`) as 'ItemCount',
  `d`.`Currency`
FROM
  (SELECT
     DISTINCT `SiteId`,
     `TransactionDate`,
     `TimeGrouping`,
     `SalesAmount`,
     `PosTransactionId`,
     `ItemCount`,
     `Currency`
   FROM
     PosSalesDev.Transaction
   WHERE
     `SiteId` = _siteId AND
     `TransactionDate` = _transactionDate
) AS `d`
GROUP BY
  `d`.`TransactionDate`,
  `d`.`TimeGrouping`;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```